# Apostrophe CMS - custom widget not working / error

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I followed the tutorial on creating a custom widget found at http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/custom-widgets.html exactly, but cannot get it to work - clicking the "+" icon does nothing (it spins into the active mode but shows no content). Also, on page load I see this error in the console:

"Your area contains a widget of type link but there is no manager for that type. Maybe you forgot to configure the link-widgets module?"

I've search for this error, and parts of it, and am pretty stumped. Any ideas?

FYI I get the same error following the contact form setup ( http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html )
"Your area contains a widget of type contact-form but there is no manager for that type. Maybe you forgot to configure the contact-form-widgets module?"

~ Am I completely missing something here? Cheers!

Comment: Can you paste in the relevant `app.js` configuration?

Comment: Sorted it thanks. It was a closing bracket in app.js modules section - thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it - was an erroneous closing bracket in app.js modules section, which meant that the modules were not being loaded. No errors on startup of app.js to show it.  Leaving this page up incase anyone else does the same!

Comment: Hi bionara, would you mind providing an example? I'm curious whether it's something we could easily detect and display a warning for. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, here's pretty much what it was:

```var apos = require('apostrophe')({
  shortName: 'sitename',
  title: 'sitename',
 modules: {
  // Stylesheets
  'apostrophe-assets': {
   stylesheets: [{
      name: 'site'
   }]
  }
  // Custom widgets
  'articles': {},
... rest of file etc
```

note the missing comma before //custom widgets, which broke the object!

Comment: Could you drop that in a gist? I have a feeling the line breaks matter here. (: gist.github.com

Comment: Sorry for the delay - here it is: https://gist.github.com/bionara/b3854f5398810c52cc80abbad613c726 Notice the missing comma on the line before //custom widgets

Comment: You just saved me hours of frustration!